# Can I change the color of text from PUT statement without using "ERROR-"/"WARNING-"/"NOTE-"?

Tags: fonts, colors, sas, put

I'm aware of the following:

```
data _NULL_;
  put "This is BLACK";
  put "NOTE: This is BLUE";
  put "NOTE- This is BLUE and has no NOTE";
  put "WARNING: This is GREEN";
  put "WARNING- GREEN, no WARNING";
  put "ERROR: This is RED";
  put "ERROR- RED, no ERROR";
run;
```

But  I was wondering if there's a way I can control the color of the resulting text in the log to be something different than the color of notes/errors/warnings/etc. In other words, I want to do this without changing the colors of other things the log prints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was discussed over at communities.sas.com a while ago, and the conclusion was NO. You can't designate a color for specific user-generated text written to the log.

https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/Colorized-Text-in-the-EG-Log/td-p/251828

https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/can-we-change-the-color-of-log-output/td-p/83991

Comment: lame. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I notice the link you posted is for EG, not base SAS. Is there a difference?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it in any SAS. But it's always risky to say "you can't do that" in a SAS forum. Added a second link where they are talking more about DM SAS. I'm not in front of SAS. If you set msglevel=i you get INFO: notes in the log. I can't remember if there may be a way to give them their own color.